# SYMBOL-VALUE of +,/ and *

Tags: operators, common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop

Consider the following code snippet:

```
[1]> (symbol-value '+)
NIL
[2]> +
(SYMBOL-VALUE '+)
[3]> (symbol-value '/)
((SYMBOL-VALUE '+))
[4]> (symbol-value '+)
(SYMBOL-VALUE '/)
[5]> *
(SYMBOL-VALUE '/)
```

So, according to my observation,

- symbol-value of `+` is the last input to the REPL.
- symbol-value of `/` is the last output of the REPL in parenthesis.
- symbol-value of `*` is the last output of the REPL as it is.

---

### What is the reason for this?

There seems to be little reason for checking what was your last input, last output, as it is already on the REPL.
So, is there any specific reason for this behaviour of these operators?
Is there any historical significance of these operator's `symbol-value`?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: They are useful when using the repl interactively. `*` and `/` (as well as `**`/`***`/`//`/`///`) allow you to pass the previous output(s) as arguments to another expression. `CL-USER> (+ 5 5)  CL-USER> (+ 10 *) ;=> 20`. `/` returns a list of values returned by the last expression, while `*` only returns the first value. `+`/`++`/`+++` can be used to pass the previous form as an argument to another expression. `CL-USER> (when t (print :foo))  CL-USER> (macroexpand +) ;=> (IF T (PRINT :FOO))`.

Comment: what does 'on the REPL' mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Symbol Value**

There is no difference between `(symbol-value '*some-special-var*)` and `*some-special-var*`. Even though they are different expressions, both compute the same value.

```
CL-USER 47 > 1
1

CL-USER 48 > 2
2

CL-USER 49 > 3
3

CL-USER 50 > (list (list *   (symbol-value '*  ))
                   (list **  (symbol-value '** ))
                   (list *** (symbol-value '***)))
((3 3) (2 2) (1 1))
```

**One reason for these variables: reusing non-readable objects in a REPL**

In Lisp one can create objects which can't be printed readably. Lisp is also not just a textual language, but also a data language. Having variables for the last results, inputs, ... makes it slightly more convenient to reuse these objects. Some Lisp listeners have more extensive mechanisms to refer to objects or parts of them. Common Lisp standardized a simple variant.

Examples for objects with no or not complete readable textual printed representation are CLOS objects, closures and function objects, streams, hashtables, some arrays, foreign data, ... Objects of these types can be printed, but the output will not be usable by the reader to get the original objects back or to reconstruct a similar object.

Often a textual representation can be read back, but won't create the same object - which sometimes would be useful.

```
CL-USER 41 > (lambda (a) (1+ a))
#<anonymous interpreted function 4060000984>

CL-USER 42 > 42
42

CL-USER 43 > (funcall ** *)
43
```

As you can see, in the above example the result of computation 41 can't be pasted and read back if it is just text.

```
CL-USER 44 > #<anonymous interpreted function 4060000984>

Error: Subcharacter #\< not defined for dispatch char #\#.
  1 (abort) Return to level 0.
  2 Return to top loop level 0.
```

There must be some mechanism to remember its value. Assigning results to standard variables is one way. Another alternative would be to copy the subforms and recompute the objects:

```
CL-USER 45 > (funcall (lambda (a) (1+ a)) 42)
43
```

But this would not work in some cases (where results might not be reproducible) or might need lots of computation time (depending on the computation performed).

Note: keeping these references to objects prevents the objects from being garbage collected, while these references exist.

Answer (score 6):

According the the [HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v__stst_.htm):

> The variables *, **, and *** are maintained by the Lisp read-eval-print loop to save the values of results that are printed each time through the loop.
>
> The value of * is the most recent primary value that was printed, the value of ** is the previous value of *, and the value of *** is the previous value of **.

For [/ and friends](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_sl_sls.htm):

> The variables /, //, and /// are maintained by the Lisp read-eval-print loop to save the values of results that were printed at the end of the loop.
>
> The value of / is a list of the most recent values that were printed, the value of // is the previous value of /, and the value of /// is the previous value of //.

And finally for [+ and friends](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_pl_plp.htm):

> The variables +, ++, and +++ are maintained by the Lisp read-eval-print loop to save forms that were recently evaluated.
>
> The value of + is the last form that was evaluated, the value of ++ is the previous value of +, and the value of +++ is the previous value of ++.

You are asking:

> What is the reason for this?

REPL is an interactive *textual* environment: in many of such systems, like unix shells, there is always some convenient way of repeating the last command, or using the last value, without having to copy explicitly such values or re-enter them (consider for instance old textual terminals, where no copy/paste operation was available). So these variables are a relic of such era (but, in spite of that, still useful to lazy people like me, that first try to get a certain value, and then, for instance, assign to a global variable such value with a simple keystroke `*`, instead of having to copy and paste the value printed).